# How do I specify multiple filters to aws ec2 describe-vpc-peering-connections?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get a list of 'active' peering connections via `aws ec2 ec2 describe-vpc-peering-connections`.  Here is what I have tried:

```
aws ec2 describe-vpc-peering-connections --region=eu-west-3 \
--filter 'Name=accepter-vpc-info.vpc-id,Values=vpc-xxxxxx Name=status-code,Values=active' \
--query 'VpcPeeringConnections[*].VpcPeeringConnectionId' --output text
```

But I get the error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--filters': Second instance of key "Values" encountered for input:
Name=accepter-vpc-info.vpc-id,Values=vpc-xxxxxxxx Name=status-code,Values=active
                                                                            ^
This is often because there is a preceeding "," instead of a space.
```

I think I need the `,` right? Is there something else I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
aws ec2 describe-vpc-peering-connections \
--region=eu-west-3 \
--filter Name=accepter-vpc-info.vpc-id,Values=vpc-xxxxxx \
--filter  Name=status-code,Values=active  \
--query 'VpcPeeringConnections[*].VpcPeeringConnectionId' \
--output text
```

OR

```sh
aws ec2 describe-vpc-peering-connections \
--region=eu-west-3 \
--filter 'Name=accepter-vpc-info.vpc-id,Values=vpc-xxxxxx' \
 'Name=status-code,Values=active'  \
--query 'VpcPeeringConnections[*].VpcPeeringConnectionId' \
--output text
```

[Combining server-side and client-side filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html#cli-usage-filter-combining)